# Website navigations and sliders

Tags: javascript, css, navigation, slider, html4

Is there a way in HTML4 to have your site navigation link to different sliders on the page.

Meaning if i have a navigatio:

Catagory 1  |  Catagory 2  |  Catagory 3  |  Catagory 4

is there a way where if a click on Catagory 1, a slider of videos will come up below pertaining to catagory 1. same for catagory 2 and so on and so forth.

Comment: Maybe search for tab view in HTML & JS.

Comment: Well, that's a tag I haven't seen in a long time.

Comment: I know :/ i wish i was doing more HTML 5, unfortunately our CMS only runs html4 at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you want to do this exactly, but here's an option:

Basically we have a nav bar with four links, each linking to an anchor:

```
<div class='nav'>
<a href="#1">1</a> | <a href="#2">2</a> | <a href="#3">3</a> | <a href="#4">4</a>
</div>
```

Then we have a container that contains four divs - each with an id relating to the anchor links in the nav bar:

```
<div class='container'>
   <div class='container1' id="1">
   Container 1
   </div>
   <div class='container2' id="2">
   Container 2
   </div>
   <div class='container3' id="3">
   Container 3
   </div>
   <div class='container4' id="4">
   Container 4
   </div>
</div>
```

Then some CSS. Some of this is just for styling purposes, but you essentially want to make your container 100% wide, with hidden x overflow.
Then, each containing div (1-4) should be set absolutely, with an offset of 100% each time.

```
.nav {
  width:100%;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15pt;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.container {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 30pt;
  width:100%;
  background: black;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.container1 {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  height:400px;
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
.container2 {
  text-align: center;
  left: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  height:400px;
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
.container3 {
  text-align: center;
  left: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  height:400px;
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
.container4 {
  text-align: center;
  left: 300%;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  height:400px;
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
```

In practice:

https://jsfiddle.net/9rfdyw27/

There are much tidier ways to do this, but I've thrown it together to at least give you an idea of where you can go with this.  You really don't need JS unless you want to make it look a bit more swish with the transition from link to link.

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining. Unfortunately the company i work for isnt keeping up with the times of HTML5 and CSS3 I appreciate you looking into this. I will try it out! much appreciated!

Comment: No problem.  It should be a breeze with HTML4 and limited CSS still; I've tried to keep it as simple as possible, but can't remember the dark ages of HTML 4 much ;-)